# Вывести ревизию svn в программе QT

Tags: windows, qt, qtcreator, svn

Есть svn репозиторий. На него время от времени закидываю проект и коммичу. Я могу как нибудь получить номер коммита и вывести его в программе?

Например в файле `versionsvn.h` было как нибудь так:

```
#ifndef __VERSIONSVN_H_
#define __VERSIONSVN_H_

#define SVN_REVISION (/*тут не знаю что!!!*/)

#endif // __VERSIONSVN_H_
```

---

UDP: Версия @Chorkov работает.

UDP: без дополнительных макросов можно сделать так:

```
DEFINES += SVN_REVISION=\\\"$$system(svnversion -n)\\\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужно учитывать, что проект может состоять из нескольких частей, и разные файлы, включенные в проект, могут принадлежать разным репозиториям, разным веткам, и иметь разные версии. Разумно ограничить себя можно, например, контролируя номер версии для папки в котрой лежит файл проекта, или какой-то конкретный файл.

Если в качестве системы сборки используется qmake, то внесите в код проекта следующею строку:

```
DEFINES+= SVN_REVISION=$$system(svnversion -n $$PWD)
```

Здесь, мы вызваем команду svnversion для текущей папки (в которой лежит *.pro файл). 
Аналогично, можно написать строчку для cmake.

В качетсве подводного камня: если в командной строке не найдется svnversion, то сообщения об ошибках компиляции будут нечитаемые.

На стороне C++ макрос может превратиться не только в числовой литерал, но и в литерал вида `1234M` или `1234:1236M` т.е. воспринимать этот макрос как число на стороне C++ - ошибка. Для обработке макроса как строки, нужно преобразовать литерал литерал в строку. Это можно сделать, относительно, стандартным макросом [BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html) из библиотеки boost.org или вручную:

```
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define SVN_REVISION_STR VALUE(SVN_REVISION)

std::cout<< SVN_REVISION_STR ;
```

Comment: Ошибка: `unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""M'`

Comment: как превратить `365M` в строку в `pro` файле?

Comment: @Kto To Все переменные в qmake - строки. Если нужно число - проще всего отрезать лишнее на стороне C++ ; `atoi(BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(SVN_REVISION))` или смириться с тем что номер ревизии строка, а не число (если в папке файлы разных ревизий, то строка может иметь вид `7842:25669M`), и для вывода в about использовать именно стоку.

Comment: у меня не работает строчка: `qDebug() << SVN_REVISION;`. Код ошибки написал выше

Comment: используйте `qDebug() << BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(SVN_REVISION) ;`

Comment: не знает что такое `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`

Comment: @Kto To:  Это макрос из boost ( `#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>` ).  Дополнил ответ примером, как можно избежать использования boost, если он еще не используется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100153/discussion-between-kto-to-and-chorkov).